# Select only one column

Tags: vba, excel

It should be extremely easy but I can't find the way of selecting only one entire column

I need to perform a loop and paste a copied column each n columns.
The problem is that when I write

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer


b = 1
'a = InputBox("Insert number", "Insert number")
a = 6

While Application.CountA(Columns(b)) > 0
    b = b + a
    Columns(b).Select
    b = b + 1
Wend
```

not only the Column(b) is selected but several are. The number varies but goes from 1 to around 10. I don't know what's wrong here! I've tried a lot of little things with the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. The command `Columns(b).Select` will select only one column, the one corresponding to the number stored in variable `b`. You have to explain what you are trying to do in more detail, eg the purpose of the `While` loop.

Comment: I have a lot of data in a worksheet and I need to export parts of it via image. There are headers at the begining that must be included in each picture, so I need a macro that copies a column and pastes it each -a- columns. Sorry if I have explained myself badly.

Comment: If you want to copy headers, maybe you need to copy the row, not the column. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Actually I need both, but columns were a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory, if you change:

```
Columns(b).Select
```

to:

```
Columns(b).EntireColumn.Select
```

Then it may work.

Comment: @Sturm, do you have any merged cells that intersect the column you are trying to select?

Comment: Yes! That was it, I just realized it and came back to SO to comment it here. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather, you are wanting to select every 6th column and insert pre-determined column values into each one.

```
Sub selectCols()
    'b=1 is your starting column, 20 is the last column, step 6 makes it go up in 6's, if needs be, you can set this to a
    For b = 1 To 20 Step 6
        'I like to do this to ensure 100% there is no carry-over of selected cells from the previous run
        Range("A1").Select

        Columns(b).EntireColumn.Select
        'do your pasting here
    Next b
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer

b = 1 : a = 6

While Application.CountA(Columns(b)) > 0
    b = b + a
    Columns(b).Copy(Sheets("MySecondSheet").Columns(b).Cells(1,1))
    b = b + 1

    Debug.Print "a = " & a & "; b = " & b ' just for debug your values
Wend
```

**EDIT:**

My code copy the entire column and paste it in "MySecondSheet". If you want to copy headers, maybe you need to copy the row, not the column.

Can you provide a screenshot?